# NLog on Xamarin.Forms .Net-Standard Project

Tags: xamarin.forms, nlog

i am writing a Xamarin.Forms app for iOS and Android. The most code is in the xamarin .net-standard project. Now I would like to use NLog as logger. I added the nuGet-paket and created an NLog.Config file under project.config folder.

It is not possible to load the logger with that configuration file. In my App.xaml.cs constructor I added:

```
LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("config\\NLog.config");
Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("console");
logger.Trace("Sample trace message");
logger.Debug("Sample debug message");
logger.Info("Sample informational message");
```

There is an exception, because the access to the path is denied... If i comment out the line

```
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("config\\NLog.config");
```

Nothing happens. NLog does not find the config. Does anybody know, if NLog is supported on Xamarin standard project? Or how to fix the problem?

greetings

Answer (score 1):

Probably, I can help you. My solution works with the .net-standard based XF projects, but it also worked with the PCL based project (with a few boilerplate classes). 
Unfortunately, I haven't tested this solution with file target output.

You need to put the XML configuration file into the library project, then edit file's properties - change the **build action** to **embedded resource**, then you need to load this file as the NLog configuration source.

The full example is here https://github.com/bondarenkod/xf-nlog-netstandart-example.
I'll try to add file as the log target later, also I'll test this example on the iOS platform.

Comment: Updated the NLog Wiki:https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading

Comment: @RolfKristensen awesome, thank you! Direct loading from assembly even faster then my old method.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NLog in our app as well, however I initialize NLog and the corresponding config (created in codebehind) in the native impmementations (AppDelegate on iOS and MainActivity on Android) and call up on the logger via a Dependency Service.
I had to do this because back then NLog wasn't available for the Portable Class Library.

If that has changed and one can finally create the logger within the shared code, I assume that you need to put your config.xml into the native app resources/assets and then in your pcl retrieve the asset/resource via a DependencyService.